# How to Justify the Output of a Pointer To Pointer char array Program

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STOP 0
void function(char**);
int main() {
    char*arr[] = { "icsp","hw6","fall","spring","autumn","winter" };
    function(arr);
    return 0;
}
void function(char**ptr) {
    char*ptr1;
    ptr1 = (ptr += sizeof(int))[-2];
    printf("%s\n", ptr1);
}
```

I have this code as my homework to explain how it works.I do not know how this pointer to pointer array really works and what does this line do `ptr1 = (ptr += sizeof(int))[-2];`?
The output is

```
fall
```

I'll be so thankful if you explain it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to solve it step by step... What value is `sizeof(int)` evaluated to? Put that value into that expression. What does `ptr += <x>` do? Etc. Try this and see how far you got. Then update your question accordingly. If you split it, it becomes easier. Due to brackets there is no problem with operator precedence but you might revisit the chapter about pointer arithmetics in your text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the function `function` the pointer `ptr` points to the first element of the array `arr` due to the implicit conversion of the last used as an argument of the function call

```
function(arr);
```

In this expression

```
ptr += sizeof(int)
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. If to assume that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the above expression is equivalent to

```
ptr += 4
```

That is now the pointer `ptr` points to the fifth element of the array `arr`, that contains a pointer to the string literal `"autumn"`.

Then there is used the subscript operator

```
ptr1 = (ptr += sizeof(int))[-2];
```

The expression

```
(ptr += sizeof(int))[-2]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( (ptr += sizeof(int)) -2 )
```

That is the pointer expression

```
(ptr += sizeof(int)) -2
```

points now to the third element of the array that is to the element (string literal) that points to `"fall"`  (the pointer moved two positions left)

Dereferencing the pointer

```
ptr1 = *( (ptr += sizeof(int)) -2 )
```

you get a pointer to the first character of the string literal that is outputted in this call

```
printf("%s\n", ptr1);
```

Answer (score 4):

`arr` is array of `char` pointers.

```
arr
----
|  |->"icsp"
----
|  |->"hw6"
----
|  |->"fall"
----
|  |->"spring"
----
|  |->"autumn"
----
|  |->"winter"
----
```

When the `function()` function is called with passing `arr` argument, the function parameter `ptr` will point to array `arr`.

```
ptr-+
    |
   ----
   |  |->"icsp"
   ----
   |  |->"hw6"
   ----
   |  |->"fall"
   ----
   |  |->"spring"
   ----
   |  |->"autumn"
   ----
   |  |->"winter"
   ----
```

Lets decode this statement

```
ptr1 = (ptr += sizeof(int))[-2];
```

Assume that on your platform `sizeof(int)` is `4` bytes, then this

```
ptr += sizeof(int)  =>  ptr += 4
```

will make `ptr` pointing to string `"autumn"`.

```
       ----
       |  |->"icsp"
       ----
       |  |->"hw6"
       ----
       |  |->"fall"
       ----
       |  |->"spring"
       ----
ptr--> |  |->"autumn"
       ----
       |  |->"winter"
       ----
```

Now, `-2` subscript when applied to resulting pointer i.e. `ptr[-2]` will give the element before `2` index of current element, which is pointer to string `fall`. It will be assigned to `ptr1`. Printing `ptr1` giving output `fall`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you:)